# Find files by pattern and copy to target location

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, regex, file-system

This is my solution to the Chapter 9 exercise in *Automate the Boring Stuff*:

> #### Selective Copy
>
> Write a program that walks through a folder tree and searches for files with a certain file extension (such as `.pdf` or `.jpg`). Copy these files from whatever location they are in to a new folder.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
#selectiveCopy.py - Walks through a folder tree with the extension .PDF and copies them to a new folder.

import re
import os
import shutil

filePdf = re.compile(r"""^(.*?)          #text before extension
          [.][p][d][f]                   #extension .pdf
          """, re.VERBOSE)

def selectiveCopy(fileExtension):
    for pdfFiles in os.listdir("/Users//Desktop/newPDFs"):
        locatedFiles = filePdf.search(pdfFiles)
        if locatedFiles != None:
            print(locatedFiles)
            files_to_copy = os.path.join("/Users/my_user_name/Desktop/newPDFs", pdfFiles)   `
            shutil.copy(files_to_copy, "/Users/my_user_name/Desktop/oldPDFs")   
            print("The following file has been copied " + files_to_copy)
selectiveCopy(filePdf)
```

I appreciate for probably all of you on here that it's not a very difficult exercise, but I've been working through this book slowly and have just decided it's probably a good idea to start putting them on a Github page.  I wanted to know if I could improve the code to make it more efficient or if there are some things I've included that aren't necessarily considered "standard practice".

Comment: Hey, welcome to Code Review! The problem description says to traverse a directory tree. This sounds to me like you actually need to descend down into sub-directories.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to recurse also into sub-folders, you should use [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk):

```
import os
import shutil

def get_files_recursively(start_directory, filter_extension=None):
    for root, _, files in os.walk(start_directory):
        for file in files:
            if filter_extension is None or file.lower().endswith(filter_extension):
                yield os.path.join(root, file)

def selective_copy(source, target, file_extension=None):
    for file in get_files_recursively(source, file_extension):
        print(file)
        shutil.copy(file, target)
        print("The following file has been copied", file)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    selective_copy("/Users/my_user_name/Desktop/newPDFs",
                   "/Users/my_user_name/Desktop/oldPDFs",
                   ".pdf")
```

As stated in the documentation, this is actually faster than `os.listdir` since Python 3.5:

> This function now calls `os.scandir()` instead of `os.listdir()`, making
>   it faster by reducing the number of calls to `os.stat()`.

I also

- added a [`if __name__ == "__main__":` guard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do) to allow importing this module from another script without running the function
- pulled the constants out into the calling code to make it re-usable
- used [`is` instead of `!=` to compare to `None`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14247373/python-none-comparison-should-i-use-is-or)
- used `str.endswith` instead of a regular expression to avoid some overhead
- changed the names to adhere to Python's official style-guide, [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Comment: I don't understand everything you did to be honest, but I'll look up some of the code, which will hopefully help me write a bit better. Thanks.

Comment: @LRBrady The one thing I did not link to in my answer:`get_files_recursively` is a [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators)

Comment: A typo here: `if filter is None`

Answer (score 6):

## Review

- Your regex can be simplified:

  There is no need for the multiple `[]` brackets - this would suffice: `r"^(.*?)\.pdf$"`.

  *Note that I escape the `.` char (which will match anything) with a backslash `\.`* to only match the specific `.` char, and the `$` to be certain that .pdf is at the end of the string.
- There is no need for Regex at all!

  1. You can either use the [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) module to directly find all files with an extension *Python3.5+*

     ```
     def get_files(source, extension):
         for filename in glob.iglob(f'{source}/**/*{extension}', recursive=True):
             yield filename
     ```
  2. use something like `.split(".")` or `filename.endswith('.extension')` to find if the file uses that extension. As @Graipher showed in his answer.
- Currently your solution works with hardcoded directories.

  To change the to directory to read or to write in, you'd need to change a lot in your code. Your solution would be much better if you could send these path locations as parameters.

Comment: I tried using the regex r"^(.*?)\.pdf" initially and it was matching a lot of other files that weren't PDFs, but I could have made an error or might have changed some code after that. Your last point what do you mean? sorry I'm still new so I don't understand.

Comment: I added a `$` to the regex so it wont match files like "afile.pdfsonething.txt"